# Difference between "I will call to you" and "I will call you"?

Tags: subcontinental-english

Can anyone pls let me know which is right phrase,

'I will call to you' or 'I will call you' ?

Comment: With *to* it means you're within shouting distance; without *to* it means you'll get a telephone call.

Comment: a typo in your question : *please

Comment: If my daughter asks when she should come downstairs for dinner, I might say "I'll call you." It doesn't *necessarily* mean I'm going to make a telephone call (although that is a very common usage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Call to"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+to) means:

> to shout to get someone's attention. I called to Fred, but he didn't
>   hear me. Did you hear me call to you?

Call simply means a "telephone call"